# Java (Android): Ive created a bunch of views using a loop, and want to GONE one of them

Tags: java, android

hi I've setup (well inflated) a bunch of buttons, which are built from a relativelayout containing buttons, textviews etc.. I want the ability to Delete/hide/Gone a whole button set. I'm assuming I can just do a `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the RelativeLayout but I'm not sure how I am to reference this layout. I have set an ID to it, but I'm really lost when trying to reference it. The button that is starting this code is a Delete button so the OnClick(View v) contains the ID of the delete button. I just tried a getparent but it didn't work out so well(crash).

can anyone point me in the right direction?

here the getparent code I tried.

```
            RelativeLayout dropping = (RelativeLayout) ((Activity) v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.tp_container);
            dropping.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I was hoping for something like this though where id could be expressed by another variable, if at all possible?

```
relativeViewVariable.id(actualId).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and this is rather embarrassing but I don't know if this is a Java or Android question?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your views dynamically then you have to set a custom ID then get the View with that ID **from it's parent!**.

```
View textView;
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout (this);
setContentView(layout);

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setId(i);
        layout.addView(textView);
}

/* FOR LOOP THAT ONE */
TextView referencedTextView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(5);
referencedTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you want to just hide ALL buttons from a layout you can then iterate through all parent views.

```
LinearLayout layout;
        View view;
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if(layout.getChildAt(i) instanceof Button){
                ((Button)layout.getChildAt(i)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
```

Comment: ah I think this is working, thanks for that. (it does mean I've had to create private variables for mylayouts in the class so I can reference them) now someone mentioned ViewGroups. think I need one of those now.

Comment: Yes for you to access a view directly you need to set an id.Also you can set a tag to the views you want GONE. All views have set/get Tag so you don't need to specify a type. If the tag is .. let's say -1 you will "GONE them" Another thing you can do it to extend a views you want to delete and implement a interface to them ,DeletableWidgets and check if they are instances of  DeletableWidgets with the second  method. But this is too much fuzz for that simple task.

Comment: ah thanks for the edit, although I have Buttons and Text and Image Views.

Answer (score 0):

if you have id's for childViews inside RelativeLayout its very much possible to do this.

```
dropping.findViewByID(R.id.ids).setVisibility(View.GONE)
dropping.removeView(dropping.findViewByID(R.id.ids))
```

and so on..

Comment: I don't think my question is ver clear, I have Id's for every component of the relative view, but when I want to GONE the relative view (which I'm hoping will GONE all the component too?) I am unsure how to reference it. my code above doesn't actually work, just causes a crash. Also I can't use the R.id.id becuase there are many of them, I have set an extra id using .setId() I want to use this to reference the relativeview.

Comment: @Purplemonkey .. You reference it in the usual way.. using findViewByID even if its gone.. if you have a crash post the logcat..

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewGroup to create set of views. Here ViewGroup will be the base class. Setting the visibility to GONE for the ViewGroup would result in setting it to the child views

Answer (score 0):

```
View menu; //Declaration
View app; //Declaration
```

Body Part

```
final View[] children = new View[] { menu, app };

    public void initViews(View[] children)
    {
        // A ViewGroup MUST be the only child of the HSV
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

        if(Your Condition)
        {
        children[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        parent.addView(children[i]);
        }       
    }
```

I have Done this kind of work in my app, just make your own condition in above function and get it Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Of course  it an android Question

first you have  inflated layout so the its instant create only once .

suppose u have created five  layout using looping  inflated layout then its all ID remain same 
(that's true the view create multiple  times ) so you cant justify the its using ID .

if you want to so what u describe in your question then you should create dynemically layout

using in the java file . like

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10  ;  i ++)
{
  RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(context);  
}
```

after that it will create new layout ID for each layout or layout component .